# Modify the model's keyspace/table with Cassandra python driver

Tags: python, cassandra

Is there a way to declare a Model (using the object mapper) and then modify its keyspace and table, whether they were initially declared or not?

The use case is the following:

- I want to maintain a [python] model of what is in the database and not have to generate dynamically this definition at runtime.
- The model can be present in multiple table/keyspace, and therefore must be accessed in those keyspaces/tables, but this is only determined at runtime and uses the same model for all the keyspaces/tables.

Comment: The solution I have found so far is to create duplicate model definitions with different table and keyspace attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cqlengine does not provide a good way to do that presently. Your best bet right now is to define an abstract model and specialize it once per keyspace by setting the `__keyspace__` attribute. You could even generate those classes dynamically by keyspace name:

```
class Base(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'my_table'
    k = Integer(primary_key=True)
    v = Integer()

for ks in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'):
    create_keyspace_simple(ks, 1)
    ks_type = type(ks, (Base,), {'__keyspace__': ks})
    sync_table(ks_type)
```

This is contrived, but shows how to generate a `ks_type` model per keyspace.

cqlengine will eventually have an intrinsic way to model this. There has been some discussion in [this ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-486). The solution will likely come with [this one](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-253).